# How to filter the price range with out apply button using angular material in angular6

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-material-6

My expected output is when the user select starting price and end price based on that i want to display the product here i don't want button by using mat-slider itself i want to sort the products. so please help me to do this?.
**Html**

```
    <mat-slider min="0" max="500" step="10" #statprice (input)="start($event)"></mat-slider>
    <mat-slider min="0" max="1000" step="10" #endprice (input)="end($event)"></mat-slider>
 <div> {{ statprice.value }} </div>
 <div> {{ endprice.value }}  </div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
 import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
    import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { Product, Category } from "../../app.models";
    import { HttpClientModule,HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-products',
      templateUrl: './products.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./products.component.scss']
    })
    export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
      data1 = 0;
      data2 = 0;
      constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
        public appService:AppService, 
        private router: Router,
        private httpService: HttpClient) {}
       start(event: any) {
        this.data1 = event;
        console.log(this.data1 );
         }
         end(event: any) {
           this.data2 = event;
        console.log(this.data2 );
         }

      ngOnInit() {}      

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use (change) or (input) event.

```
<md-slider (input)="onInputChange($event)"></md-slider> onInputChange(event: any) { console.log("This is emitted as the thumb slides"); }
```